# my code isn't reading the array from user

Tags: arrays, c

I'm supposed to read an array from the user, but it doesn't work. What is the problem? I preferer not to use pointers.

`SIZE` is defined to be 100.

```
void get_array (char array[])
{
int i=0;
    for ( i=0;i<SIZE || array[i]=='\n';i++)
    {
        scanf("%c",&array[i]);
    }
 }
```

I'm reading the function in the main like that :

```
get_array(array);
```

Comment: Please [edit] and show a [mcve]. The code you show is fine.

Comment: Oh, maybe ```array[i]=='\n'``` -> ```array[i] != '\n'```

Comment: What do you mean by "it isn't work"?

Answer (score 0):

You can use two methods:

First, you can use `break` to jump out of loop.

```
for ( i=0;   i<SIZE, array[i-1] != '\n' ;i++ ){
  scanf("%c",&array[i]);
  if(array[i] == '\n')
    break;
}
```

Second, use`arr[i-1]` to get your input data because when `scanf` done, it will do `i++`, and then check whether `i < SIZE` and `array[i-1] != '\n'`.

```
for ( i=0;   i<SIZE, array[i-1] != '\n' ;i++ )
{
   scanf("%c",&array[i]);
}
```

Comment: What are you want? Can you give me more details?

Comment: i want to scanf until I get 'Enter ' from user or until the size of the array is over 100

Answer (score 0):

You fix it, see the code below:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

#define SIZE 10

void get_array (char array[])
{
int i=0;
    // array[i]=='s' It is just useless
    for ( i=0;i<SIZE;i++)
    {
        scanf(" %c",&array[i]); // Note the space before %c
    }
 }


int main() {
    char mArray[SIZE];
    
    get_array(mArray);
    
    printf("\n========Entered characters========\n");
    for(int i=0; i<SIZE; i++) {
        printf("%c\n", mArray[i]);
    }
}
```

The output:

```
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j

========Entered characters========
a
b
c
d
e
f
g
h
i
j
```

**Update**
Here is another output from my computer:

```
YouCanDoIt!

========Entered characters========
Y
o
u
C
a
n
D
o
I
t
```

Since it accepts 10 inputs we just can't see the *!* mark.

Comment: `'s'` -> `'\n'`, the OP has changed the code.

Comment: I see, but it makes no change in the way that my code works . Because I skipped the space character in the `scanf` function.

Comment: i changed the space but its still isnt working

Comment: Since I don't see your main code I couldn' say anything. First copy and paste my code, try it, if it works on your computer, then you might be missing something in your main code.